# Rendering Polymer element once per multiple attribute changes

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have an Polymer.dart element with multiple attributes, e.g.

```html
<code-mirror lines="{{lines}}" widgets="{{widgets}}">
</code-mirror>
```

on some occasions `lines` and `widgets` change simultaneously sometimes only `widgets` changes.

I would like to rerender component once independently on how many properties change in the same turn of event loop.

Is there a way a good built-in way to achieve that?

Additional trouble here is that interpretation of `widgets` depends on content of `lines` and ordering in which `linesChanged` and `widgetsChanged` callbacks arrive is browser dependent, e.g. on Firefox `widgetsChanged` arrives first before `linesChanged` and component enters inconsistent state if I do any state management in the `linesChanged` callback.

Right now I use an auxiliary class like this:

```dart
class Task {
  final _callback;
  var _task;

  Task(this._callback);

  schedule() {
    if (_task == null) {
      _task = new async.Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 50), () {
        _task = null;
        _callback();
      });
    }
  }
}

final renderTask = new Task(this._render);

linesChanged() => renderTask.schedule();
widgetsChanged() => renderTask.schedule();
```

but this looks pretty broken. Maybe my Polymer element is architectured incorrectly (i.e. I have two attributes with `widgets` depending on `lines`)?

Answer (score 1):

`*Changed` methods are definitely the right way to approach the problem. However, you're trying to force synchronicity in an async delivery system. Generally we encourage folks to observe property changes and react to them and not rely on methods being called in a specific order.

One thing you could use is an `observe` block. In that way, you could define a single callback for the two properties and react accordingly:

http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#observeblock

Polymer's data binding system does the least amount of work possible to rerender DOM. With the addition of `Object.observe()`, it's even faster. I'd have to see more about your element to understand what needs rendering but you might be creating a premature optimization.

Comment: Observe block definitely looks like what I'd need, thanks! (though it is not ported Polymer.dart now but I guess it will be at some point). As for premature optimization. I encountered this problem with three components separately. Only in one of them I do this as an optimisation and there a single *full* rendering can take anything from .5s to 30s because the DOM I build is proportional to the size of loaded V8 IR, and I have an example where it goes to 70k values which translates to 70k table rows generated, each with many DOM nodes inside. Rendering this twice is not an option

Comment: Though 30s btw should be more like 2seconds but shadow_dom polyfill introduces 10-15x hit according to my measurements. I am planning to mitigate this particular case by rendering IRs lazily on scroll similar to infinite scrolling. So this was optimization case. As for two other components, I have the problem that one attribute  has no usefull meaning without another attribute so I have to wait until both changes are propagated to actually render something. Here is what I ended up doing: https://code.google.com/p/irhydra/source/detail?r=8d35760fb3ab038a82fe8ee612bd8a3044f50320&name=polymerized

Comment: @ebidel, are you saying that the observe callback will only be called once in a microtask even if two properties it's observing have changed? This would be neat, but it's not clear from the documentation, and it would be a bit inconsistent with the {oldValue, newValue} argument list.

Comment: @JeffreyYasskin: I can confirm that the callback is only called once with the observe block, regardless if you specify oldValue and 
newValue (they will be set to one of the attributes).

See here: http://jsbin.com/nilim/3/edit

Answer (score 1):

I think there are three possible solutions: 
See this: http://jsbin.com/nilim/3/edit

1. Use an observe block with one callback for multiple attributes (the callback will only be called once)
2. Create an additional attribute (i.e. `isRender`) that is set by the other two attributes (lines and widgets). Add a `ChangeWatcher` (i.e. `isRenderChanged()` in which you call your expensive render method)
3. Specify a flag (i.e. `autoUpdate`) that can be set to `true` or `false`. When `autoUpdate` = `false` you have to call the `render` method manually. If it is set to `true` then `render()` will be called automatically.

The disadvantage of solution 1 is that you can only have one behavior for all observed attributes. Sometimes you want to do different things when you set a specific attribute (i.e. size) before you call render. That's not possible with solution 1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a better way. You may omit the 50ms delay (just `Timer.run(() {...});`)  as the job gets scheduled behind the ongoing property changes anyway (my experience, not 100% sure though)